# How to select rows which have same value in some column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data table "menu" like this

```
id     name             type
-----------------------------
10     tea              drink
20     krabby patties   food
30     coffee           drink
40     kelpo            food
50     kelp shake       drink
```

I want to select all `id` of `drink`, like this

```
id
---
10
30
50
```

i'm sorry, can you help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its just a simple query, search by your self @J.St

Comment: We can help you, But first give a try and share the results. Small help: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not show any effort to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id from menu where type = 'drink';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic  SQL you can simple search and find it

```
SELECT ID FROM menu WHERE TYPE='drink';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use [**`IN Operator`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

**Query**

```
SELECT id FROM menu
WHERE type in ('drink');
```